# I am getting an error "arg list too long" in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh, aix

i am using the following command and getting an error "arg list too long".Help needed.

```
find ./*  \
  -prune         \
  -name "*.dat"  \
  -type f        \
  -cmin +60      \
  -exec basename {} \;
```

Comment: try `find ./ -name "*.dat" -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \;`

Comment: need to use star to get the desired output...@МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: why do you need it? which output is desired for you?

Comment: МалъСкрылевъ check this out                    wms /files/hostin:>find ./  -prune -name "*.dat"  -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \;
wms /files/hostin:>find ./*  -prune -name "*.dat"  -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \;
DPART_ITEM_0009_0003599.dat
DPART_ITEM_0099_0002016.dat
DPART_ITEM_0099_0002083.dat
FOOT_ITEM_0009_0003599.dat
FOOT_ITEM_0099_0002016.dat
FOOT_ITEM_0099_0002083.dat
PART_ITEM_0009_0003599.dat
PART_ITEM_0099_0002016.dat
PART_ITEM_0099_0002083.dat
wms /files/hostin:>find . -prune -name "*.dat"  -type f -cmin +60 |xargs -i basename {}
wms /files/hostin:>

Comment: Could you update the question, to set it desired output, because I see the only comparison of...

Comment: i need to find all the .dat files which are older than 60 minutes in the present directory

Comment: Well @МалъСкрылевъ first comment should give you exactly that. Unless you need the names in a different format

Comment: @user2819785 i've updated the answer again (added croppen version of find, for aix maybe)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fix

```
find . -prune -name "*.dat"  -type f -cmin +60 |xargs -i basename {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

To only find files in the current directory, use `-maxdepth 1`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.dat' -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \;
```

Comment: max depth not a valid argument

Comment: More properly, it's a GNU extension.

Comment: Which OS are you running on? And maxdepth is all one word.

Answer (score 1):

In all *nix systems the shell has a maximum length of arguments that can be passed to a command. This is measured after the shell has expanded filenames passed as arguments on the command line.

The syntax of find is `find location_to_find_from arguments....`. so when you are running this command the shell will expand your `./*` to a list of all files in the current directory. This will expand your find command line to `find file1 file2 file3 etc etc` This is probably not want you want as the find is recursive anyway. I expect that you are running this command in a large directory and blowing your command length limit.

Try running the command as follows

`find . -name "*.dat" -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \;`

This will prevent the filename expansion that is probably causing your issue.

Comment: check this out                    wms /files/hostin:>find ./  -prune -name "*.dat"  -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \;
wms /files/hostin:>find ./*  -prune -name "*.dat"  -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \;
DPART_ITEM_0009_0003599.dat
DPART_ITEM_0099_0002016.dat
DPART_ITEM_0099_0002083.dat
FOOT_ITEM_0009_0003599.dat
FOOT_ITEM_0099_0002016.dat
FOOT_ITEM_0099_0002083.dat
PART_ITEM_0009_0003599.dat
PART_ITEM_0099_0002016.dat
PART_ITEM_0099_0002083.dat
wms /files/hostin:>find . -prune -name "*.dat"  -type f -cmin +60 |xargs -i basename {}
wms /files/hostin:>

Comment: Sorry. Removed the prune

Comment: If i use find ./* i am getting the output in one directory but in other directory it says "Arg list too long. If i use find ./ and remove the * here then i do not get any output.

Comment: And what happens if you remove the -prune and run the command as `find ./ -name "*.dat" -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \; ` as mentioned by @МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: if i remove prune it searches in all the subdirectories which is not desired.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, although the proposed solution apparently isn't exactly what the OP was looking for.  (Poor question, then.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to show only **.dat** filename in the **./** tree. Execute it without `-prune` option, and use just path:

```
find ./ -name "*.dat" -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \;
```

To find all the **.dat** files which are older than 60 minutes in the present directory only do as follows:

```
find . -iregex "./[^/]+\.dat" -type f -cmin +60 -exec basename {} \;
```

And if you have croppen (for example [aix](/questions/tagged/aix)) version of [find](/questions/tagged/find) tool do as follows:

```
find . -name "*.dat" -type f -cmin +60 | grep "^./[^/]\+dat" | sed "s/^.\///"
```

Comment: I guess if the OP is stuck on AIX `find`, it also won't support `-iregex`.

Answer (score 0):

Without find, and only checking the current directory

```
now=$(date +%s)
for file in *.dat; do
    if (( $now - $(stat -c %Y "$file") > 3600 )); then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

This works on my GNU system. You may need to alter the date and stat formats for different OS's